# PostgreSQL driver crash crash at SQLColAttribute

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, unixodbc

**Description**: 
i am using postgresql database as a backend,connecting to **postgresql with unixodbc driver manager and libodbc++ library and psqlodbc driver**. when i try to run my application to query some data it is getting crashed. It is getting crashed
at random functions.

i cannot exactly trace which function it is crashing.

it is crashing at three functions like

**1.  SQLColAttribute
2.  SQLGetInfo**

PostgreSQL version number you are running:

How you installed PostgreSQL:PostgreSQL 9.1 linux ubuntu

Changes made to the settings in the postgresql.conf file: No

Operating system and version:linux ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit)

What program you're using to connect to PostgreSQL:libodbc++-0.2.3 (libodbc++) library

PostgreSQL odbc driver : psqlodbc version(3.03)

ODBC using: unixODBC-2.3.2

For questions about any kind of error:

Description : i am trying to connect  my application to PostgreSQL. while i am trying run select query's it is getting crashed at certain functions.

i am using linux ubuntu (12.04) with unixODBC (2.3.2), PostgreSQL database (9.1), psqlodbc driver (3.03) , libodbc++-0.2.3

Thanks & Regards
Balakrishna

This is the BackTrack report generated.

```
#5  0x0000000002114936 in SQLGetInfo (connection_handle=0x7fff7003f190, info_type=151, info_value=0x7fffdfff93f4, buffer_length=4, string_length=0x7fffdfff93fa)
    at SQLGetInfo.c:560
        connection = 0x7fff7003f190
        ret = 0
        s1 = "\033\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\033\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@\226\377\337\377\177\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\225\fd\366\377\177\000\000-\023\005p\377\177\000\000\002\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\033", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "@\226\377\337\377\177\000\000\355M\364\366\377\177\000\000-\023\005p\377\177\000\000\002\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\200\223\377\337\377\177\000\000\211\332\362\366\377\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000R\221\350\001\000\000\000\000\220\361\003p\377\177\000\000\257\223\377\337\377\177\000\000-\023\005p\377\177\000\000+\023\005p\377\177\000\000(\023\005p\377\177\000\000\002\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\037\005p\377\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\070\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\220 \005p"
#6  0x00000000020dd764 in odbc::DatabaseMetaData::_getNumeric32 (this=0x7fff70051a20, what=<optimized out>) at databasemetadata.cpp:150
        res = <optimized out>
        t = 4
        r = <optimized out>
#7  0x0000000002100085 in odbc::DriverInfo::DriverInfo (this=0x7fff70052090, con=0x7fff7003eec0) at driverinfo.cpp:59
        md = 0x7fff70051a20
        r = <optimized out>
#8  0x00000000020dbeef in odbc::Connection::_connect (this=0x7fff7003eec0, dsn=..., user=..., password=...) at connection.cpp:213
        r = <optimized out>
#9  0x00000000020d9e4f in odbc::DriverManager::getConnection (dsn=..., user=..., password=...) at drivermanager.cpp:260
        con = 0x7fff7003eec0
#10 0x000000000133f105 in ODBCDatabase::Connect (this=0x7fff70053f40, properties=...) at StoreGrid/source/Database/ODBC/ODBCDatabase.cpp:134
        retryCount = 5
        triedCount = 1
        postgresConnectionString = {static npos = <optimized out>,
          _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x2e09678 ""}}
        sgConfig = 0x4f5c7e
```

Comment: A backtrace from the crash would be very helpful.

Comment: #5  0x0000000002114936 in SQLGetInfo (connection_handle=0x7fff7003f190, info_type=151, info_value=0x7fffdfff93f4, buffer_length=4, string_length=0x7fffdfff93fa)    at SQLGetInfo.c:560
        connection = 0x7fff7003f190
        ret = 0
        
#6  0x00000000020dd764 in odbc::DatabaseMetaData::_getNumeric32 (this=0x7fff70051a20, what=<optimized out>) at databasemetadata.cpp:150
        res = <optimized out>
        t = 4
        r = <optimized out>
#7 in odbc::DriverInfo::DriverInfo (this=0x7fff70052090, con=0x7fff7003eec0) at driverinfo.cpp:59

Comment: *Please* use the formatting guidance. Augh. Also, that's only part of the backtrace ... what happened to the original trap message and to frames 0 through 4? Rather harder to tell what's going on without those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem. The problem for the crash was due to UnixODBC library. it was fixed with UnixODBC 2.3 version.